# To convert For loop into foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How I can convert below mentioned for loop into foreach loop? Can anyone assist me to fix this?

```
 @for (int rCount = 0; rCount < @Model.ItemFilters.Categories.Count; rCount++)
{
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably, you need this?

```
@foreach (var category in @Model.ItemFilters.Categories)
{
     //some code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either run a loop using the foreach syntax like

```
 @foreach (var cat in @Model.ItemFilters.Categories)
  { .....}
```

Or use the ForEach method on a List (ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110)

```
     @Model.ItemFilters.Categories.Foreach(cat => .....)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use the following code as well.
don't forget of using System.Lind;

```
@Model.ItemFilters.Categories.OfType<YOUR_CATEGORY_TYPE>.ToList().ForEach(child =>
        {
            //AMK: do some stuff
        });
```